# Runtime Error 3075 -systax error (missing operand ) in VBA Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am getting 3075 error with this statement :

```
sql = "UPDATE [qr_code] SET [qr_code].[sequence]=[qs_code].[sequence] FROM [qr_code] RIGHT JOIN [qs_code] ON [qs_code].[sequence_ref]=[qr_code].[sequence_ref]"
DoCmd.RunSQL sql
```

It works in SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using MS Access' Create / Query Design tool makes me think that the SQL statement should be

```
UPDATE [qr_code] RIGHT JOIN [qs_code]
    ON [qr_code].[sequence_ref] = [qs_code].[sequence_ref]
   SET [qr_code].[sequence] = [qs_code].[sequence];
```